# Manually computed Mann–Whitney U-test differs from R's output

Tags: r, self-study, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I found a sketchy lecture notes about Mann–Whitney U-test. There where were given data

```
X: 30 32 33 33 36 37 40 44
Y: 27 29 31 34 34 35 41
```

It was computed that

$U_-=8+8+7+4+4+4+1=36$,
$U_+=0+0+1+4+4+4+7=20$

and said that alternative hypothesis $H_{12}:Y<X$ gives the $P$-value:

$$P(U<20)=P((20-28)/8.64)=\Phi(-0.925)=0.1772$$

I was wondering what would be some nice way to do the computations by computer? I tried R but it looks I don't know how to use it:

```
> a = c(30, 32, 33, 33,36,37,40,44)
> b = c(27, 29, 31, 34, 34, 35,41)
> wilcox.test(a,b, alternative="less", correct=FALSE)

        Wilcoxon rank sum test

data:  a and b
W = 36, p-value = 0.8232
alternative hypothesis: true location shift is less than 0
```

Or is it just rounding issue as $1-0.1772=0.8228\approx 0.8232$?

Comment: What is the output when you use `alternative="greater"` instead?  If there's any rounding error, it's on your part, so you should be able to tell whether $0.1772$ should be considered the same as $0.1768$.